# Why not Weise, dass?

Tags: conjunction

In conversation with 2 native German speakers I said:

> Die Infektionsweise bezieht sich auf die Weise, **dass** die Infektion von einer Person zur anderen übertragen wird.

They corrected me like this:

> Die Infektionsweise bezieht sich auf die Weise, **wie** die Infektion von einer Person zur anderen übertragen wird.

Can someone explain the correction, please?

I expected my German to correspond with the English sentence:

> The mode of infection refers to the way **that** the infection is transmitted from one person to another.

This would not be English:

> The mode of infection refers to the way **how** the infection is transmitted from one person to another.

Comment: Shouldn't it be "... the way in which the infection ..." or "... the way the infection ..." in proper English? Or am I subconsciously germanizing English here? The German equivalent would be: "... bezieht sich auf die Weise, auf die die Infektion ..." Which feels cleaner to me than "...die Weise, wie ...".

Comment: The "how" version might not "proper" English, but it's not unheard of, at least in the particular area of rural North America I'm from. I guess part of the question is why the "how" isn't allowed, seeing as that's what it means. In other words "that" instead of "how" seems more like an irregularity in English than something you should expect to be followed in German.

Comment: This question is answered here: [When to use wie or dass?](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/65564/when-to-use-wie-or-dass)

Answer (score 5):

- dass = that

  > Die Infektionsweise bezieht sich auf die Weise, **dass** die Infektion von einer Person zur anderen übertragen wird.
  > <sub>The mode of infection refers to the mode **that** the infection is transmitted from one person to another.</sub>
- wie = how

  > Die Infektionsweise bezieht sich auf die Weise, **wie** die Infektion von einer Person zur anderen übertragen wird.
  > <sub>The mode of infection refers to the mode **how** the infection is transmitted from one person to another.</sub>

The mode of an action doesn't tell you, **that** something happened. The mode tells you **how** (in which way) it happened.

Comment: I'm afraid the example is not entirely lucid because the that-£variant might as well pass in an informal context, but *die Weise wie* is a set collocation. Not a native English speaker, just saying.

Comment: I'm also not a native English speaker. Please, if you can give a better answer: do it!

Comment: I think the main point here is that while "that" and *dass* aren't interchangeable, even in the limited case where they're used to start a relative clause. German seems to prefer using *wie* whenever you're talking about "how" something is done, even, as in this case, when "that" would be preferred in English.

Comment: A reference that elaborates on this point would be most helpful.

Comment: What kind of reference are you thinking of? This is how native speakers like me use German language.

Comment: I would like a reference that explains to me the difference between my example and this example in DWDS: "Dies gelang Yntema auf die Weise, daß er das verladene Gewicht aller Produktarten mit Hilfe von Kosten-Äquivalenzziffern addierbar machte." #12: https://www.dwds.de/r/?h=1&corpus=kern&q=auf+die+Weise&from=wb

Comment: @user44591: This is a new Question. feel free to ask it: https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/ask